# Problem with initialization of vector of vector of shared_ptr class

Tags: c++, class, vector, shared-ptr, make-shared

I'm trying to initialize a vector of vector of shared_ptr class of size 19x19 ( _goban ).

```
class Goban
{
  public:
    Goban();
    ~Goban();
  private:
    vector<vector<shared_ptr<Cell>>> _goban;
};
```

My constructor is like that :

```
Goban::Goban() : _goban(18, vector<make_shared<Cell>>(18, new Cell))
{
}
```

I can't find the way to initialize.

I got this error :

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator /* = allocator<_Tp> */>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You specified the wrong template argument `make_shared<Cell>`, which should be `shared_ptr<Cell>`. And note that the implicit conversion from raw pointers to [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) is prohibited. Then

```
Goban::Goban() : _goban(18, vector<shared_ptr<Cell>>(18, make_shared<Cell>()))
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
}
```

With the help of [deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/deduction_guides), you can even omit specifying the template argument as

```
Goban::Goban() : _goban(18, vector(18, make_shared<Cell>()))
{
}
```

Comment: Note that this code is creating 18x18 `shared_ptr`s that all refer to a single `Cell` object in memory, it is not creating 18x18 separate `Cell` objects.  If you need that, you will have to call `make_shared()` using loops, eg: `Goban::Goban() { _goban.resize(18); for (auto &v : _goban) { v.resize(18); for(auto &v2 : v) { v2 = make_shared<Cell>(); } } }` Depending on use, it may be easier to create a 1D vector instead: `vector<shared_ptr<Cell>> _goban; ... _goban.resize(18*18); for (auto &v : _goban) { v = make_shared<Cell>(); }` then use math to convert 2D indexes into 1D indexes when needed